# Can't set cookie with domain or HTTPS

Tags: php, cookies, ssl, https

So here's what I'm doing

```
setcookie("UID", 'Hey', time()+3600*24*120, '/', 'http://localhost/', isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true);
```

And I've also tried this

```
setcookie("UID", 'Hey', time()+3600*24*120, '/', 'http://localhost/', true);
```

So I then go on the page, and nothing happens. The cookie isn't set. When I get rid of the domain and SSL, it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe the domain should be .localhost

Comment: Just tried that. And still the same issue @QuinnFTW